# Maven Plugins - how to require a license

Tags: java, licensing, maven-plugin

I would like to make my plugin require a license to run similar to the maven clover plugin.  Is there some utility out there that I can generate licenses with that will also allow me to integrate that into the plugin?

I need to do the following steps.

1. Modify the existing plugin to validate the license file
2. Generate the license file online and store the information for retrieval later.

Thanks,
Walter

Comment: I checked the Padlock integration guide, the API looks clean and easy to use. However, Padlock doesn't seem to offer any anti-spoofing mechanism as Easy Licenser do (http://www.agilis-sw.com/ezlm/antispoofingProtection.htm). No offense, but it looks **very easy** to remove Padlock API calls and this makes it pretty useless. PS: I don't have any relationship with Agilis Software.

Answer (score 1):

If you use something too weak, it will always be possible to decompile the invoking class, remove the verification, compile the new class and add it back to the jar. So, unless you have some method of *inline* code in a lot of methods to do a complex validation of a string from the license data, use a tool that does something more.

You could try for example:

- [Easy Licenser](http://www.agilis-sw.com/ezlm/index.htm) from Agilis Software (uses Java so integration is straightforward)

  > [...] Java is our native language so integration is straightforward, and we are familiar with the issues you need to consider when protecting Java applications. Our license management solutions include protections such as digital library signatures (to make sure the libraries haven't been 'spoofed' or tampered with), guidelines on how to use exception-based flow of control to conceal the license check call itself, as well as protection against clock roll-back on time-limited licenses.
- [LM-X License Manager](http://www.x-formation.com/lm-x_license_manager/index.html) from X-Formation (uses JNI so make your application platform dependent)

But mostly the entry point to the license manager is vulnerable. With decompilers you can remove those calls from the software. Obfuscators make it a lot harder, but not impossible.

The mentioned solutions don't seem too be very expensive. However, if you decide to build your own solution, this open-source library might help: [TrueLicense Library Collection](https://truelicense.dev.java.net/).

In all cases, I don't think these tools offer the "web integration" you're looking for (something a la Atlassian if I understood well your requirement). It looks like you'll have to implement a custom solution for that.

Comment: +1: for pointing out that any license checking can be disabled by finding and removing calls to the license checker.

Comment: Good point, but how much effort is involved?  For instance the maven clover plugin requires a license right and won't run without it.  Would it be more beneficial/productive to open source it and ask for donations to support development and then charge for support?

Comment: I suggested to use an existing solution, Easy Licenser, and not to build your own. So I'm not sure to understand your question. Now, regarding clover, I don't use it, I prefer Cobertura which is open source and free.